# InputSplit Mapper JobTracker Interaction

Tags: hadoop, io, mapreduce

Below is my understanding about InputSplits and their interaction with the mappers...please correct me if I am wrong somewhere...

The InputFormat generates the InputSplits and a map task is spawned for each inputsplit.
For data locality usually a map slot is chosen on the datanode that physically carries the block which that InputSplit refers to. Imagine that there is no replication of data here.

What will be the case if there is no map slot available on the datanode where the block is ?
Will the jobtracker wait for getting an empty slot on this datanode and then schedule the mapper on this datanode or will it schedule the map on any other node where there is a map slot free and then stream the data from the first datanode ?

Answer (score 1):

The latter. You can see the following counters in your job:

```
Data-local map tasks=46
Rack-local map tasks=5
```

The number of Data-local map tasks means how many map tasks are running on the same datanode without transferring the data through network. The number of Rack-local map tasks means how many map tasks are running on the different datanode with transferring the data through network.

The number of `Rack-local map tasks` only takes into account the nodes local to the rack. If you have some tasks which use the data of some nodes in the different rack (means there is no slot in the same rack), it will be countered by `Other local map tasks`. However, such tasks need to transfer the data cross the rack. You can confirm the logic of the datenode selection [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobInProgress.java#1727).

Comment: In the Rack-local case, does it take into account the data that is local to the rack i.e it may involve data transfers across nodes present in the same rack but not across racks ?